# What can you do that is useful with Haskell Type Classes?

Tags: haskell

I understand that type classes are very useful for organizing data and for type checking etc., but other than what is already included in prelude, is there ever a need to define your own class?

Under almost any circumstance one could just define a data or newtype and get almost the same effect anyways. Using the built in "Ord", "Eq", "Show", and others seems to be enough to do anything you would want to do with classes.

When I looked up projects for classes in Haskell I get a lot of example classes like so:

```
class Foo a where
    bar :: a -> a -> Bool
```

If there is a reason to use type classes, does anyone have a good project for a beginner to practice using them or some good form guides for them?

Comment: Classes are used for "ad hoc" polymorphism. You can see it as interfaces in object-oriented programming.

Comment: Is this a joke? There's dozens of classes outside the prelude in the `base` package alone, and probably thousands more on Hackage. Ord, Eq, and Show are just a tiny tip of an ice cube chipped off the top of the iceberg.

Comment: You make two great points, or at least allude to them.  1. You can get very far with data types and first class functions - ad hoc polymorphism is often unnecessary or over-used.  2. Internalizing what classes give that are not provided by data types and higher order functions will help you design your code.

Comment: As others have indicated, there are plenty of useful and/or powerful classes out there. You should learn to use some of them and to define your own instances. But you don't have to jump straight into defining your own *classes*. It takes a fair bit of experience, trial, and error to work out what makes a good class. Take your time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Type classes provide *ad hoc* polymorphism, as opposed to parametric polymorphism: a function does not need to be defined the same way (or at all) for each type. In addition, it does so in an *open* fashion: you don't need to enumerate all the types that implement the class when you define the class itself.

Some prominent examples of non-standard type classes are the various `MonadFoo` classes provided by `mtl` (monad transformer library), `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` provided by the `aeson` library, and `IsString`, which makes the `OverloadedString` extension work.

---

Without type classes, you can define a function that works for a single argument type

```
foo :: Int -> Int
```

or one that works for *all* argument types

```
foo :: a -> Int
```

The only way to work for some subset of types is to use a sum type

```
foo :: Either Int Bool -> Int
```

but you can't later define `foo` for `Float` without changing the type of `foo` itself

```
foo :: Either Int (Either Bool Float) -> Int
```

or

```
data IntBoolFloat = T1 Int | T2 Bool | T3 Float
foo :: IntBoolFloat -> Int
```

either or which will be cumbersome to work with.

Typeclasses let you work with one type at a time, and let you add new types in a nonintrusive fashion.

```
class ToInt a where
    foo :: a -> Int

instance ToInt Int where foo = id
instance ToInt Bool where
    foo True = 1
    foo False = 2
instance ToInt Float where
    foo x = 3  -- Kind of pointless, but valid
```

An instance of `ToInt` can be defined anywhere, although in practice it's a good idea for it to be defined either in the module where the class itself is defined, or in the module where the type being instantiated is defined.

---

Underneath the hood, a method (a function defined by a type class) is essentially a mapping of types to functions. The `TypeApplications` extension makes that more explicit. For example, the following are equivalent.

```
foo True == 1
foo @Bool True == 1 -- foo :: ToInt a => a -> Int, but foo @Bool :: Bool -> Int
```

Answer (score 7):

In adition to chepner's explanation of the usefulness of type classes, here are some more practical examples of type classes outside of Prelude:

- [`Arbitrary`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck/docs/Test-QuickCheck-Arbitrary.html) from QuickCheck ([A QuickCheck Tutorial: Generators](https://www.stackbuilders.com/news/a-quickcheck-tutorial-generators)).
- [`Example`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hspec/docs/Test-Hspec.html#t:Example) from Hspec, which is similar but not exactly equivalent.
- [`WithLog`](https://github.com/kowainik/co-log/blob/master/co-log/tutorials/2-custom/Custom.md#example) (or rather, `HasLog`) from [co-log](https://github.com/kowainik/co-log).
- [`SafeCopy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safecopy/docs/Data-SafeCopy-Internal.html#t:SafeCopy) is another serialization class, but with different constraints than Aeson's `FromJSON`, `ToJSON`, since it also deals with data format migrations.

Since there's a whole design space for using type classes in different ways, here are some more thoughts:

- The *Has* Type Class Pattern: [Tutorial 1](https://medium.com/hackernoon/the-has-type-class-pattern-ca12adab70ae), [Tutorial 2](https://rashadg1030.github.io/rashad-blog/7.html#appenv-and-the-has-typeclass-pattern), and the package [data-has](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-has).
- An interesting library related to QuickCheck is [Hedgehog](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hedgehog), which does away with type classes for a [strong reason](https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/quickcheck-hedgehog-validity) (tutorial and generally an eye-opener). So there may be lots of reasons to use and not use type classes; often there simply already exists exactly the type class you're looking for.
- It may be worth to read Gabriel Gonzalez' [Scrap Your Type Classes](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html) which highlights some of the downsides of the uses of type classes. As the blog post starts with, his "*opinion on type classes has mellowed since I wrote this post, but I still keep it around as a critique against the excesses of type classes.*"

> If there is a reason to use type classes, does anyone have a good project for a beginner to practice using them or some good form guides for them?

It really depends on whether you want to define a type class, or just define type class instances for existing type classes, use an existing type class in base, or use some type class in an extended library.

It can be fun to define type class instances for things that are [`Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Monoid.html) or [`Semigroup`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Prelude.html#t:Semigroup) ([tutorial](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids)). It can also be fun to define your own `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` instances for some JSON data format that you might find interesting ([tutorial](https://artyom.me/aeson)).

Answer (score 4):

The definition

```
class Foo a where
    bar :: a -> a -> Bool
```

is very simililar to

```
class Eq a where
    (==) :: a -> a -> Bool 
    (/=) :: a -> a -> Bool
```

and here is when you can find how useful can it be:

Imagine you've got slugs, and want to know if they can procreate, and there is a rare species with hermaphrodite type, you can use your typeclass:

```
data Slug = M | F | H

class Foo a where
    bar :: a -> a -> Bool

instance Foo Slug where
   bar H _ = True
   bar _ H = True
   bar F M = True
   bar M F = True
   bar _ _ = False
```

Or, with temperatures:
You want to know if mixing water will get you warm water:

```
data Temp = Cold | Hot | Warm

instance Foo Temp where
   bar Warm _    = True
   bar _ Warm    = True
   bar Hot Cold  = True
   bar Cold Hot  = True
   bar _ _       = False
```

So, that typeclass now could be named sort of "Mixable", and the method, "mix", and it would be less confusing to read for type `Slug` and `Temperature`.

Now, if you want to watch it in action with some example, I can came up now with something like...

```
mix :: Foo a => [a] -> [a] -> [Bool]
mix xs ys = zipWith bar xs ys

$>  mix [M,M,H,F] [F,F,F,F]
=> [True,True,True,False]
```

but there is a restriction with mix, you can just mix Mixable things. so if you do:

```
mix [1,1] [2,2]
```

will break:

```
9:1: error:
    • No instance for (Foo Bool) arising from a use of ‘mix’
    • In the expression: mix [True, True] [False, True]
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = mix [True, True] [False,
```

And that means, that you can organize you data types to satisfy the `mix` function according its structure, or your needs.

Level 2:

What if you want a default implementation for Slug and Temp? Because you saw they where similar, so you could do:

```
class (Bounded a, Eq a) => Mixable a where
    mix :: a -> a -> Bool
    mix e1 e2 = e1 /= e2 || any (\x -> x /= minBound && x /= maxBound) [e1, e2]

data Slug = F | H | M deriving (Bounded, Eq, Show)
data Temp = Cold | Warm | Hot deriving (Bounded, Eq, Show)

instance Mixable Slug
instance Mixable Temp

mixAll :: Mixable a => [a] -> [a] -> [Bool]
mixAll xs ys = zipWith mix xs ys

main = do
  putStrLn $ show (mixAll [F,F,F,M,M,M,H] [F,M,H,M,F,H,H])
  putStrLn $ show (mixAll [Cold,Cold,Cold,Hot,Hot,Hot,Warm] [Cold,Hot,Warm,Hot,Cold,Warm,Warm])
```

> [False,True,True,False,True,True,True]
>
> [False,True,True,False,True,True,True]